# preg_split() problem with strings containing '&'

Tags: php, preg-split

I am using `preg_split()` to get array of sentence from a string.

```
$sentences = preg_split("/([.?!\r\n]+)/", $text, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY|PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

But when `$text` contains '&', for example:

```
$text = 'this is test. we are testing this & we are over.';
```

then it stops matching after the '&'.

Comment: Could you clarify "this we stop after &"? Does it stop parsing the string or does it split at the ampersand (&) or what?

Comment: I would update your regex to catch more sentence types and not drop the `.`. `([^.?!]+(?=[.?!]['"]?\s*)(?:[.?!]['"]?\s*))` worked for me, but I might have missed other obscure types of sentence endings/beginnings. After getting the matches (not splitting), run trim to get rid of the spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your preg_split handles sentences with ampersands correctly, for example:

```
$text = 'Sample sentence. Another sentence! Sentence with the special character & (ampersand). Last sentence.';
$sentences = preg_split("/([.?!\r\n]+)/", $text, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY|PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
print_r($sentences);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Sample sentence
    [1] => .
    [2] =>  Another sentence
    [3] => !
    [4] =>  Sentence with the special character & (ampersand)
    [5] => .
    [6] =>  Last sentence
    [7] => .
)
```

Comment: This was error with ajax that i used to send the text with & splited it.php works fine. this is problem with ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Your Script:

```
$text = 'this is test. we are testing this & we are over.';
$sentences = preg_split("/([.?!\r\n]+)/", $text, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY|PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
echo '<pre>'.print_r($sentences, true).'</pre>';
```

My Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => this is test
    [1] => .
    [2] =>  we are testing this & we are over
    [3] => .
)
```

I don't understand your problem.